# Need some understanding on Attunity connection with SAP ECC on Oracle

Tags: oracle, attunity

I am trying to create Attunity endpoint for SAP ECC on Oracle. From the Attunity documentation, it seems to be a two step process.

1. Create a Oracle DB endpoint connection (passing connection string and credentials)
2. Use the above configuration (as Backend) in SAP Application endpoint

I know that once you have access to DB, you can retrieve the data. So in this case, why is step two required?
Since I am yet to get access over Oracle in the organization, I could not try it yet (Facing some other issues). But wanted to understand what could be the logic behind the same.
I could not find relevant article on google, so thought if any one has tried to perform the same - can guide me through this.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Hello I am not sure if you got the answer.. but how attunity pulls the data is you can create a logstream and then if you have a Primary and Disaster recovery server (generally an organisation has 2) so you can read from the logstream avoiding the pull twice .. but the steps would be create an authentication to that server .. enable supplemental logging for the tables and then read that supplemental logging a delta changes.